# My website won't allow zooming on instagrams web browser?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, zooming, mobile-safari, instagram

When I go to my website www.melonheadnj.com on safari I can pinch to zoom.  However, when I click my link on my instagram page @melonheadnj I am unable to zoom.

I checked other links from other pages and they were able to zoom.

Would this be something in my mobile css?

Answer (score 0):

In my theme's header.php file there was a meta tag...

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' name='viewport' />
```

By deleting the user-scalable=no, I was then again able to zoom in on the instagram browser.  Weird that it was allowing me to zoom on safari mobile already though?

Answer (score 0):

As already noted the viewport metadata is preventing native zoom. However, in Mobile Safari (webkit), Apple has chosen to no longer respect `user-scalable=no` and `maximum-scale` so user will always be able to natively zoom no matter what. This is to force accessibility support. See the webkit [blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/7367/new-interaction-behaviors-in-ios-10/) on this.